# Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно добавить в код, чтобы считалось время не только разных песен при вводе, но и одинаковых

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
violator_songs = [
    ['World in My Eyes', 4.86],
    ['Sweetest Perfection', 4.43],
    ['Personal Jesus', 4.56],
    ['Halo', 4.9],
    ['Waiting for the Night', 6.07],
    ['Enjoy the Silence', 4.20],
    ['Policy of Truth', 4.76],
    ['Blue Dress', 4.29],
    ['Clean', 5.83]
]

l = []
summ = 0
n = int(input('Сколько песен выбрать? '))
for i in range(1, n + 1):
  print('Название', i, 'песни:', end=' ')
  song_name = input()
  l.append(song_name)

for k in violator_songs:
  if k[0] in l:
    summ += k[1]

print('\nОбщее время звучания песен', round(summ, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще будет, если вы сконвертируете список песен в словарь.

```
violator_songs_dict = dict(violator_songs)
```

(ну, или изначально его забьёте как словарь, где ключ - название, а значение - длительность)

А далее цикл по списку введённых песен. А условие по наличию в  словаре.

```
for k in l:
  if k in violator_songs_dict:
    summ += violator_songs_dict[k]
```